# Ubuntu Translation in fon

Tags: translation

I want to translate Ubuntu in *fon* (my language). The Fon is most spoken language of Benin.

Could someone let me know how I can do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you showing interest in contributing to the community. You should probably check out http://translations.ubuntu.com/ (Although I seem to be having some problems in navigating the website, perhaps it's a local issue). You'll get all the info you need there and you'll be up and translating in no time. Cheers!

Comment: I have some problems in navigating the website too.

Comment: I think the website issue is a temporary one and should be fixed soon.